# Does an object's properties need to be explicitly declared in order to set them with setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can an object's properties be set when the object arrives instead of when it is declared in the constructor?

```js
      this.state = {
        mydata: {},
      }
```

Toy reproducible using [DogCEO](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/):

```js
class Test extends Component 
{
    // Initialize the state
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        mydata: {},
      }
      this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }
    // Fetch the list on first mount
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData() {
        const url = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';
        console.log("fetching", url);
        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
          const thedata = data.message;
          console.log(thedata);  
          this.setState({mydata: thedata});
        });
    }
```

I've been attempting to do with various permutations of syntax. Neither of these seem to work.

`this.setState({mydata: thedata});`

`this.setState(prevState => ({mydata: thedata}));`

Comment: Seems like it should! Can you see what's going on in the reproducible? @HoldOffHunger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feasible, but a bit dirty.

```js
this.setState((prev) => ({ mydata: { ...prev.mydata, thedata } }));
```

The code updates the value of `mydata` to a copy of `mydata`, and at the same time, also appends the values of `thedata` into `mydata` object.

Read more about [object destructuring syntax](https://medium.com/@justintulk/javascript-object-cloning-shallow-copies-in-x-d11bd1d9c3f1).

**Keep in mind that this only works for shallow copies, that is objects without nested properties. If an object is nested, you'll have to perform deep copies.**

EDIT: Seems like your problem (`setState` is undefined) happens because you misplaced a `}` in your `componentDidMount`.

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    } // you're missing this one.

    getData() {
        const url = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';
        console.log("fetching", url);
        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
          const thedata = data.message;
          console.log(thedata);  
          this.setState({mydata: thedata});
        });
    }
```

EDIT #2: So, I discovered that the error is because you're using `this` value in the wrong context. The value of `this` can change depending on the context that it is called in. To fix this, we can use arrow functions, so the `this` will always be bound to the parent class. It's also better for readability.

```js
    getData() {
        const url = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';
        console.log("fetching", url);
        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const thedata = data.message;
          console.log(thedata);  
          this.setState({mydata: thedata});
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Cannot read property setState of undefined - so perhaps a deep copy is required?

Comment: this (from your article link) doesn't work either: `const thedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like you got a typo - that's why the `setState` is undefined.

Comment: That looks like it! I'd been trying `getList = () => {` notation as well and was getting nowhere. I knew it had something to do with `this` but couldn't see it Cheers.

Comment: I know right! I suggest you to try moving to arrow functions and functional components. They are **much** easier to handle!